# NSView rounded corner drawn wrong

Tags: objective-c, macos, drawing, nsview, rounded-corners

I'm on OSX, XCode 8.2, Objective-C

I have a window with a background Image:

```
self.window.titleVisibility = NSWindowTitleHidden;
self.window.titlebarAppearsTransparent = YES;
self.window.styleMask |= NSFullSizeContentViewWindowMask;
self.window.movableByWindowBackground = YES;
self.window.opaque = NO;       
self.window.backgroundColor = [NSColor colorWithPatternImage:[NSImage imageNamed:@"background.jpg"]]];
```

In that window i have an `NSTabViewController`. On one of those `NSTabViews` i draw an `NSView` with rounded corners:

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(NSRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        self.layer = _layer;   // strangely necessary
        self.wantsLayer = YES;
        self.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
        self.layer.cornerRadius = 10.0;
    }
    return self;
}
```

My Problem is that even if the corners are round, there's still that bright white corner visible.

[image]

The answer here ([rounded corners on NSView using NSBezierPath are drawn badly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30950099/rounded-corners-on-nsview-using-nsbezierpath-are-drawn-badly)) didn't work for me because i have a background image - although it works WITHOUT background image. But i'd like to keep that image because the window is then draggable by clicking its background.

I also tried to use an `NSImageView` for my background image, move it to the back and override it's `mouseDownCanMoveWindow` method. That works too for the dragging, but still not for the corner drawing.

Any help appreciated

Comment: It looks to me like you're just seeing the window (or some other view) *behind* the view with the rounded corner.  If you want everything rounded, then you probably need to round one of your outermost container views instead of specific "leaf" subviews.

Comment: I already wrote that it WORKS without the background image in the NSWindow. So there's nothing behind - i also checked that technically.